# Why do I have folders called "1" in my document library after an upgrade to 2010?

Tags: 2010, document-library, upgrade

We upgraded our MOSS2007 to MSS2010 (database attach upgrade method). We have multiple document libraries on a site. default.aspx contains web parts with the files from document libraries.

The files in document libraries are structured in folders. When I click on a folder, I get a mess of files and folders in all other doclib-webparts.

To demonstrate this I created two document libraries with the following structure:

```
tmp1 (doclib)
   tmp1_1 (folder)
      tmp1_1_1 (file)
      tmp1_1_2 (file)
      tmp1_1_3 (file)

Test (doclib)
   sdfsdf (folder)
      Test_1_1 (file)
      Test_1_2 (file)
      Test_1_3 (file)
```

When I create a new page (test.aspx), it automatically creates a new folder "1", som the url is ../SitePages/1/test.aspx

When I uploaded documents it suggests me the folder "1", but in the AllItems.aspx view there is no folder 1.

But when I click on a folder (**tmp1_1**) in one of my doclib webparts on the ../SitePages/1/test.aspx I get:

[image]

So I see the three files inside the clicked folder **tmp1_1** as usual. But the second folder is messed up. I see the expected folder **sdfsdf** and all the files inside the **sdfsdf** and the ''ghost'' folder **1**.

It happens only in the migrated site. It never happened in the original MOSS 2007 site. And it doesn't happen in the freshly created SP2010-sites.

Why are these folders appearing, and how can I fix them?

Comment: can be the same as [Why is a folder automatically created named 1](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19111/why-is-a-folder-automatically-created-named-1-in-document-libraries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have only seen this functionality in Meeting Workspaces before. Each time you schedule a new Meeting in the same Workspace, a new folder will be created in the Document Library (1,2...) to store the documents for that specific meeting.
The first folder therefore is one. Maybe you've migrated to a Meeting Workspace Template by accident?